# Mustache javascript: how to handle with boolean values

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have a javascript object `obj` and the value of the key can be `true` or `false`.

This value is passed to mustache template.

// javascript object

```
obj = {
    like: true // or false
}
```

// template

```
<span>
   {{ like }}
</span>
```

Now I would like having the result of the rendering in this way:

```
<span>
   Like <!-- If {like: true} --->
</span>

<span>
   Unlike <!-- If {like: false} --->
</span>
```

What is the best way to make it in mustache template?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

it's just like this:

```
<span>
    {{#like}}
        Like <!-- If {like: true} --->
    {{/like}}
    {{^like}}
        Unlike <!-- If {like: false} --->
    {{/like}}
</span>
```

Comment: can we put condition as (like == 2) ... {{#like==2}}

Comment: In order to do something more complex than "if" or "unless", you'll need to create a helper. Something like this: https://gist.github.com/doginthehat/1890659

Answer (score 14):

Just use a section and an inverted section:

```
{{#like}}
<span>
   Like <!-- If {like: true} --->
</span>
{{/like}}

{{^like}}
<span>
   Unlike <!-- If {like: false} --->
</span>
{{/like}}
```

Comment: I like this answer a lot more than the accepted answer because the resulting span may have its own class that should apply to it accordingly. For example, the "like" or "dislike" may be displayed as a thumbs up or thumbs down.