# check for boolean false in mustache.js

Tags: json, templates, boolean, mustache

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114037/mustache-javascript-how-to-handle-with-boolean-values), checking for `false` in a json object that you pass to mustache template is done like this:

```
{{^like}}
    it is false
{{/like}}
{{#like}}
    it is true
{{/like}}
```

assuming that the json looks like this `{"like":true}`

but trying this out on the [Mustache demo page](http://mustache.github.io/#demo) is not working out as expected. The html output is shown like this:

```
it is true
it is false
{{/like}}
```

Why is it breaking when you have `{{^whatever}}` in your template? Is it not the right way to check for `false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inverted sections (^) are implemented on the [**Mustache github**](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/blob/master/mustache.js), but the [**MustacheDemoIO**](http://mustache.github.io/#) uses obsolete version of the library that doesn't support that. In the obsolete code you can find:

```
// for each {{#foo}}{{/foo}} section do...
  return template.replace(regex, function(match, name, content) {
    var value = that.find(name, context);
    if(that.is_array(value)) { // Enumerable, Let's loop!
      return that.map(value, function(row) {
        return that.render(content, that.merge(context,
                that.create_context(row)), partials, true);
      }).join("");
    } else if(value) { // boolean section
      return that.render(content, context, partials, true);
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  });
```

but there is nothing for {{^foo}} {{/foo}}. That's why it brakes on your example.

But that shouldn't be a big problem, because the newest version that is available on the [**Mustache github**](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/blob/master/mustache.js) has this functionality.

Comment: So there was never such a thing! I woundr why that answer got so many upvotes.

Comment: The reason for that is that the latest Mustache code on the [**github**](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/blob/master/mustache.js) has this functionality. My guess is that [**MustacheIO**](http://mustache.github.io/) uses obsolete version of the Mustache library.

Comment: That's true, on the website it renders just fine, the problem is only at the demo page